# how to save checkbox value in database in following situation?

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Hi everyone I am a facing one issue by using jquery I am a allowing user to upload a file on check but it is a not a necessary to upload a file on check but in my PHP it checking that file is uploaded or not if file is not uploaded than it is not allowing to save a checkbox value in database so how can I resolve this issue and I want to save a both in database checkbox value and file is uploaded for which checkbox?

PHP code:

```
//declare variable for get value of checkbox
$j = 0;
//loop for check every input file name to check it user is uploaded file?
for($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++){
    // if size of file is higher than 0 bytes than it can upload
    if($_FILES['checkboxfile'.$i]['size'] > 0){
        // get checkbox value
        $checkboxvalue = $checkbox[$j];
        // lets upload file
        if($this->upload->do_upload('checkboxfile'.$i)){
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            // get filename
            $filename = $upload_data['file_name'];
            //array for saaving data in database
            $checkboxinfo = array(
                'UniqueID'=>$uniqueid,
                'Product'=>$checkboxvalue,
                'Image'=>$uniqueid.'/'.$filename
            );
            $this->Postingad->checkbox($checkboxinfo);
        }
        $j++;
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label for="email">electronics
          <input type="checkbox" name="product_category[]" value="electronics" id="product_category" class="electronics">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="efileu" style="display:none;" >
          <input type="file" name="checkboxfile0" id="efile"   style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label for="email">kitchen
          <input type="checkbox" name="product_category[]" value="kitchen" id="product_category" class="kitchen">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="kfileu" style="display:none;" >
          <input type="file" name="checkboxfile1" id="kfile"   style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label for="email">Decoratives / Interior
          <input type="checkbox" name="product_category[]" value="decoratives / Interior" id="product_category" class="Interior">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" id="dfileu" style="display:none;" >
          <input type="file" name="checkboxfile2" id="dfile"   style="width:100%">
        </div>
```

Comment: foreach ($_FILES['file']['name'] as $filename) 
            {}

Comment: File selection is on respectively checkbox.

Comment: How can I identify this file is for which checkbox?

Comment: You should really use some punctuation when writing your question. It's really hard to read and understand it as it currently is.

Comment: Then you can use different  names for each input type file

Comment: Sorry man but my English is very weak please try to understand what  I want to say.